# Use combobox value in different WPF form class

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a WPF window which the user can select items in a combobox drop down.

Once they press a button, another WPF window will open. I want to be able to use the drop down selection value in the other WPF window class.

I've just started working with WPF windows so apologies if this should be simple.. below is what I've tried but had no luck with.

A class which holds the combobox values:

```
public class ComboSelection
{
    public string cFunction { get; set; }
    public string cItem { get; set; }
}
```

Creating an instance of the class and assigning the properties values and opening the second WPF window:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboSelection combo = new ComboSelection();
    combo.cFunction = ComboBox3.Text;
    combo.cItem = ComboBox2.Text;
    Pick_Item pi = new Pick_Item();
    pi.Show();
}
```

When I try to reference the class in the other WPF window class, I get the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property`.

I tried making the properties static, and then that shows a compile error of `Member 'myProject.ComboSelection.cFunction.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just skim your question a little but the most noticeable thing here I would like to comment about is your calling convention, in WPF we call it Window, not Form. You should *throw* much stuff from Winforms away when switching to WPF, of course *throw* here does not mean you have to forget it but just not to mix up Winforms and WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ComboSelection` parameter to the `Pick_Item` constructor and pass `combo` into your new instance of `Pick_Item`

```
class Pick_Item
{
    private ComboSelection _comboSelection;

    public Pick_Item(ComboSelection comboSelection)
    {
        _comboSelection = comboSelection;
    }
}
```

...

```
Pick_Item pi = new Pick_Item(combo);
pi.Show();
```

Now your Pick_Item class has access to the ComboSelection as a class-level variable.

Comment: I'm getting `'myProject.Pick_Item' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments` when passing in `combo` to the instance of `Pick_Item`. I've added `private ComboSelection _comboSelection;` at the top of the `Pick_Item` class.

Comment: I forgot to add the parameter to the constructor. I type code straight into the website instead of using an IDE so sometimes miss bits out. see updated answer